# iOS 8 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Trying to dismiss UIAlertController with unknown presenter.'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8

iOS8 has deprecated `UIAlertview` and needs to use `UIAlertController`.

I am trying to compile using Xcode 5.1 and running it on an iOS 8 beta 4 device, so I am unable to instantiate `UIAlertController` directly. I see that there is no issue in using `UIAlertView` in most places in the code base except for couple of classes i.e Appdelegate and initialViewController of storyboard.  I have tried to create a custom viewcontroller to handle `UIAlertView` to see if it is fixed but in vein. Any clue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please paste detailed code and better explanation of what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add a delay before showing the alert view using following kind of code :

```
 dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC); 
            dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                UIAlertView *crashAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert"
                                                                     message:@"XYZ"
                                                                    delegate:self
                                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                                           otherButtonTitles:@"Yes",@"Always", nil];
                [crashAlert show];

            });
```

This worked for me.

Comment: Not very elegant, @Kavish. I call this a smelly quickfix :)